# do I have to fly directly into France with my student visa 3b? Im canadian

Tags: visas, air-travel, canada, france, exchange

Im currently buying my airplane tickets to get me from Canada to France. Im going there on exchange.

I have the 3b exchange student visa but does this mean that i need to fly directly into France? Because it would be cheapest to fly to London, clear customs and take another flight the next day. Or even fly to Frankfurt and take the train to my destination in France!

Any info would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to fly directly to France.

As a Canadian, you don't require a visa to enter the UK, so it's fine for you to fly through London.

France and Germany are both part of the Schengen area, so they effectively have unified immigration control.  If you travel through Germany to get to France, you'll go through passport control in Germany rather than in France (you may be checked on the train, but it's not usually automatic).  That's also fine.

Comment: +1, small edit to answer the obvious question.